# Check what methods were used on element query

Tags: elementquery

I am creating plugin that provides helper methods for constructing search forms, filtering entry lists
by various params etc. And for that plugin, I need to be able to tell which methods were alredy used on element query object - because if you use same method twice, only second one will be taken into account.

So, it is possible to check if for example `relatedTo` was used on specific element query object already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, you can check if an `ElementQuery` parameter has been set by checking the corresponding property name: it will be `null` if the parameter hasn't been set, and have the previously set value otherwise.

**Examples**

This will output `6`:

```
  {% set query = craft.entries().relatedTo(6) %}
  {{ dump(query.relatedTo) }}
```

This will output `null`:

```
  {% set query = craft.entries() %}
  {{ dump(query.relatedTo) }}
```